# How to upload more than 25 mb file to jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I get the error note :
Cannot upload file (>25 MB)
while trying to upload >25 MB file via
http://localhost:8888/tree

---

Update:

conda list gives:

jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_3
jupyter_client            4.4.0                    py35_0
jupyter_console           5.0.0                    py35_0
jupyter_core              4.2.0                    py35_0

jupyter notebook --version gives:
4.2.3

pip install --upgrade notebook , after quit long processing gives an error note .

Answer (score 1):

Ok , it's seems that http://localhost:8888/tree files are in :
C:\Users\user\Documents
so big files can be uploaded directly to there.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are using an old version of the notebook, as this issue (https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/96) details that this was fixed in version 5.0.0.

Run `jupyter notebook --version` on the command line or run this in a notebook cell:

```
import notebook
print(notebook.__version__)
```

If your version is older than 5.0.0, run `pip install --upgrade notebook` to upgrade.

Comment: Do you know what is the jupyter notebook  http://localhost:8888/tree   files address ?

Comment: no my jupyter notebook version is something like this then also I getting large file issue..
5.6.0